# How do I find a string (and some lines before and after) in a huge file by terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, find

I want to display three or four lines before and after a certain string in a really huge file, which I can' topen with vi. How is this done?

I tryed

```
grep -i -n -r 'mysearchstring'
```

but this only gives me one line. I need some lines before and after to get the context!

Thanks!

I once have seen a terminal command, that does that, but I forgot and I can't find it again. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use grep with the `-A` (how many lines to display after the match) and `-B` (how man lines to display before the match) parameters:

```
grep -i -n -r -A 4 -B 4 'mysearchstring' file.xml
```

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked this option while reading the man page myself. But found it later on. ;-) Please complete your example, so that it shows how to search within a given file, and I will be glad to accept your answer. =)

Comment: I would suggest that `-A4 -B4` could be shortened with `-C4`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
grep -n -A 5 -B 5 'searchstring' file.xml
```

This finds `searchstring` in `file.xml` and display 5 lines trailing and 5 leading lines.